# What's the proper way to use startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges in swift 4?

Tags: ios, core-location, swift4

I try to make a running app, and I want to use the method `startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges`, but I'm missing something because is not firing the `didUpdateLocations` that the documentation says it should.

I have successfully used the startUpdatingLocation method of the `CLLocationManager` class and I can totally can use it for my interests, but I'd like to understand why my implementation doesn't work.

So, I have this code:

```
let locationManager = CLLocationManager()
func determineMyCurrentLocation() {

    locationManager.delegate = self
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
    locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
    locationManager.allowsBackgroundLocationUpdates = true

    print("authorization Status: \(CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus().rawValue)")

    if CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled() {
        locationManager.startUpdatingLocation() //(1)
        //(2)locationManager.startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges()
        locationManager.distanceFilter = 20
        //locationManager.start
        //locationManager.startUpdatingHeading)(
    }
}

func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) { print("yaaay!") }
```

If you comment (1) and uncomment 2 the func locationManager...etc is never fired.

Also, I have my info.plist with the proper keys set, "Privacy - Location When In Use Usage Description" and "Privacy - Location Always and When In Use Usage Description").

Any idea?

Thanks in advance.

EDITED: My question was imprecise. I put the locationManager property as a class member and I completed the properties in my info.plist

Comment: Your location manager needs to be a property,  not a local variable that willl be released when the function exits. Also you need a new permission key for iOS 11 - "alwaysandwheninuse"

Answer (score 2):

The `startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges` requires always authorisation. That also means you should turn on "Background Modes" in Capabilities section and selection "Location Updates". You also require the `Privacy - Location Always Usage Description` Try these two and you should receive significant location change updates.

Comment: This is not true. One of the advantages of using `startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges` is that you do NOT have to set Background Mode - Location in your plist (Apple will scrutinize this to make sure it is really essential to your application - it is a serious privacy issue, after all, and a battery drain). You will have to get the user's permission to track via the usual `requestAlwaysAuthorization` before you start monitoring location changes. And do not set `CLLocationManage.allowsBackgroundLocationUpdates` as this will cause an assertion without the Background Mode - Location set.